# Unzip multiple files in parallel using powershell

Tags: powershell, unzip

I am trying to achieve parallel unzip using PowerShell. The code attached would unzip one file at a time that matches the keyword. Is there a way I could unzip multiple files in parallel

[image: Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a workflow which will provide parallel processing
You can learn alot more about workflows at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-1801

```
workflow Unzip-File{
    Param (
        [Object]$Files,
        [string]$Destination,
        [switch]$SeprateFolders
    )
    foreach –parallel ($File in $Files){
        if($SeprateFolders){
            Write-Output "$($file.Name) : Started"
            Expand-Archive -Path $File -DestinationPath "$Destination\$($file.Name)"
            Write-Output "$($file.Name) : Completed"
        }else{
            Write-Output "$($file.Name) : Started"
            Expand-Archive -Path $File -DestinationPath $Destination
            Write-Output "$($file.Name) : Completed"
        }      
    }
}

try{
    $ZipFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Default\Desktop\ZipTest\Source\*.zip
    Unzip-File -Files $ZipFiles -Destination "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\ZipTest\Destination" -SeprateFolders
}catch{
    Write-Error $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give this a try: https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline

```
$Zipfiles = gci [...]

$ZipFiles | Split-Pipeline -Count 10 {process{ Expand-Archive -Path $_ -DestinationPath [...] }}
```

You could also start a job for each item, then recieve them at the end of the loop. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-6